# Probability distribution of dependent uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Given $P_r\;{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}\;uniform(Pconst-a,Pconst+a)$
I want to modify $P_t$ in such a way, that it's range is symmetrically dependent on random variable  $\xi \in [0,1]$ like this:
$P_r\;{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}\;uniform(\xi(Pconst-a),\xi(Pconst+a))$
PDF of $\xi$: $f_{\xi}(z) = \frac{2}{\pi \sqrt{1-z^2}},\; z \in [0,1]$

The problem is that I fail to express PDF of the modified $P_r$
I am trying to do it like this:

\begin{equation}
    f_{P_r | \xi}(z | y) = 
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{2a y}, \; \substack{ z \in \left[ y(P_{const}-a), y(P_{const}+a) \right] \\ 
                                   y \in (0,1]
        }\\
        0, \; otherwise  
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:theProblem}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    f_{P_r}(z) =
    \begin{cases}
         \int_{0}^{1}{ f_{P_r | \xi}(z | y) f_{\xi}(y) } dy ,\;
        z \in \left[ P_{const}-a, P_{const}+a \right] \\
        0, \; otherwise  
    \end{cases}
        \label{eq:res}
\end{equation}

but I clearly need to use $f_{P_t, \xi}(z,y)$ in $f_{P_r | \xi}(z | y)$.
So the problem, I guess, boils down to me not knowing how to derive $f_{P_t, \xi}(z,y)$